# Structure with signed integer bit-fields resulting minus outputs

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

This is the C code with a struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    struct{
        int a : 4;
        unsigned int b : 3;
        int c : 3;
    } x;

    x.a = 7;
    x.b = 7;
    x.c = 7;

    printf("%d\n",x.a);
    printf("%d\n",x.b);
    printf("%d\n",x.c);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above C program `x.c` has allocated 3 bits from memory but resulting an output result as `-1`. What is the reason for this?

Comment: 7 = 111 in binary. So sign bit gets 1, which makes the value negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data member c is defined as having type int (that is `signed int` in case of your compiler) and have only 3 bits to represent signed values. So the most significant bit is considered as the sign bit, 7 in the binary notation looks as

```
111
```

where the left-most bit is used as the sign bit due to the definition

```
int c : 3;
```

So this combination of bits means that the number is negative and equal to `-1`.
The maximum positive value that can be stored in this bit field is equal to `3`

```
011
```

and the minimum negative value is equal to `-4`

```
100
```

Take into account that it is **implementation defined** whether a bit field defined as having type `int` will be interpretated as `unsigned int` or `signed int`. Your compiler consideres a bit field of type `int` as having type `signed int`
So it is better to explicitly specify either `signed int` or `unsigned int` for bit fields.

From the C Standard

> ...except that **for bitfields**, it is **implementation-defined** whether the
>   specifier int designates the same type as signed int or the same type
>   as unsigned int.

Answer (score 1):

In [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representation#Two.27s_complement), -1 is represented as 11111111......... {as many as number of bits }
When you assign 7, which is 111 in binary, the sign bit gets 1, and remaining bits get 1 and 1.

Now,
sign bit = 1 => number is negative
remaining bits = 11 => 1 in two's complement.

Hence the result is negative one

note: from the behavior, it appears your machine implements two's complement

Answer (score 1):

The difference between an `int` and `unsigned` datatype is the significance of the sign bit. In the above code, you are using int for x.c with 3 bits to store the value 7, which in binary translates to 111. When you print the value in x.c, using %d, it is taken as the sign bit to be set. If you are on a little-endian machine and if you initialize it with any value higher than 4, you would be setting the sign bit and getting a result of two's complement as MAKZ said in his answer. 
so

7 will print as -1, 6 will print as -2, 5 will print as -3, 4 will print as -4